# Vector bundles with flat connections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ and $W$ be varieties defined over a number field, and let $f: V \rightarrow W$ be a map. Suppose that the induced map on the complex points of $V$ and $W$ induces an isomorphism on fundamental groups of $V(\mathbb{C})$ and $W(\mathbb{C})$.

By Deligne, there's a correspondence between algebraic vector bundles (over $\mathbb{C}$) with flat connections having regular singular points on $V$, and $W$. Does the same hold over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Comment: I think the question is, whether the pullback of a vector bundle defined over the algebraic numbers is again defined over the algebraic numbers This should be ok, as the morphism $f$ is defined over the algebraic numbers, so one should see this from the variety-description of a vector bundle, as given in Hartshorne's book on page 128. Another way to see it, would be using Galois-descent, which for the extension ${\mathbb C}/\bar{\mathbb Q}$ is possible.

Comment: Not quite - if I start with a vector bundle with flat connection defined over $\mathbb{C}$ which pulls back to one defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, what about the one I started with?